# Postal Code Validation Rules for multiple countries

Tags: formula, validation, account, validation-rule, address

I'm trying to make a rule that validates postal codes but it doesn't seem to work. For example when I chose Portugal and I input 8 characters ZIP code it does not work. In fact it doesnt work for any of them. Here is the code in the validation rule:

```
OR( 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Faroe Islands" , 
BillingCountry = "Iceland", 
BillingCountry = "Lesotho" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{3} ")) 
, 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Austria" , 
BillingCountry = "Belgium" , 
BillingCountry = "Switzerland" , 
BillingCountry = "Costa Rica" , 
BillingCountry = "Cyprus" , 
BillingCountry = "Denmark" , 
BillingCountry = "Liechtenstein" , 
BillingCountry = "Luxembourg" , 
BillingCountry = "Norway" , 
BillingCountry = "New Zealand" , 
BillingCountry = "Philippines" , 
BillingCountry = "Slovenia" , 
BillingCountry = "Tunisia" , 
BillingCountry = "Venezuela", 
BillingCountry = "South Africa" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{4} ")) 
, 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Germany" , 
BillingCountry = "Algeria" , 
BillingCountry = "Spain" , 
BillingCountry = "Finland" , 
BillingCountry = "France" , 
BillingCountry = "Greece" , 
BillingCountry = "Croatia" , 
BillingCountry = "Indonesia" , 
BillingCountry = "Israel" , 
BillingCountry = "Iran" , 
BillingCountry = "Italy" , 
BillingCountry = "South Korea" , 
BillingCountry = "Kuwait" , 
BillingCountry = "Monaco", 
BillingCountry = "Mexico" , 
BillingCountry = "Malaysia" , 
BillingCountry = "Saudi Arabia" , 
BillingCountry = "Thailand" , 
BillingCountry = "Turkey" , 
BillingCountry = "Ukraine" , 
BillingCountry = "Vietnam" , 
BillingCountry = "Yugoslavia" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{5} ")) 
, 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Canada" , 
BillingCountry = "China" , 
BillingCountry = "Czech Republic" , 
BillingCountry = "India" , 
BillingCountry = "Kazakhstan" , 
BillingCountry = "Nepal" , 
BillingCountry = "Poland" , 
BillingCountry = "Romania" , 
BillingCountry = "Russian" , 
BillingCountry = "Sweden" , 
BillingCountry = "Singapore" , 
BillingCountry = "Slovakia"), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{6} ")) 
, 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Japan" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{7} ")) 
, 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Argentina" , 
BillingCountry = "Portugal" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{8} ")) 
, 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Brazil" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{9} ")) 
, 








OR(BillingCountry = "CAN", BillingCountry = "CA", BillingCountry = "Canada"), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "((?i)[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[A-Z]?\\s?\\d[A-Z]\\d)?")) 
)
```

//EDIT

Here is the second version of the code which still doesnt work. It doesn't work because no matter what I put in there it still comes up with the same Error Message which I've put in the validation rule which is "invalid postal code"

```
OR( AND ( 

OR ( 
BillingCountry = "Faroe Islands" , 
BillingCountry = "Iceland", 
BillingCountry = "Lesotho" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{3} ")) 
),AND( 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Austria" , 
BillingCountry = "Belgium" , 
BillingCountry = "Switzerland" , 
BillingCountry = "Costa Rica" , 
BillingCountry = "Cyprus" , 
BillingCountry = "Denmark" , 
BillingCountry = "Liechtenstein" , 
BillingCountry = "Luxembourg" , 
BillingCountry = "Norway" , 
BillingCountry = "New Zealand" , 
BillingCountry = "Philippines" , 
BillingCountry = "Slovenia" , 
BillingCountry = "Tunisia" , 
BillingCountry = "Venezuela", 
BillingCountry = "South Africa" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{4} ")) 
),AND( 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Germany" , 
BillingCountry = "Algeria" , 
BillingCountry = "Spain" , 
BillingCountry = "Finland" , 
BillingCountry = "France" , 
BillingCountry = "Greece" , 
BillingCountry = "Croatia" , 
BillingCountry = "Indonesia" , 
BillingCountry = "Israel" , 
BillingCountry = "Iran" , 
BillingCountry = "Italy" , 
BillingCountry = "South Korea" , 
BillingCountry = "Kuwait" , 
BillingCountry = "Monaco", 
BillingCountry = "Mexico" , 
BillingCountry = "Malaysia" , 
BillingCountry = "Saudi Arabia" , 
BillingCountry = "Thailand" , 
BillingCountry = "Turkey" , 
BillingCountry = "Ukraine" , 
BillingCountry = "Vietnam" , 
BillingCountry = "Yugoslavia" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{5} ")) 
),AND( 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Canada" , 
BillingCountry = "China" , 
BillingCountry = "Czech Republic" , 
BillingCountry = "India" , 
BillingCountry = "Kazakhstan" , 
BillingCountry = "Nepal" , 
BillingCountry = "Poland" , 
BillingCountry = "Romania" , 
BillingCountry = "Russian" , 
BillingCountry = "Sweden" , 
BillingCountry = "Singapore" , 
BillingCountry = "Slovakia"), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{6} ")) 
),AND( 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Japan" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{7} ")) 
),AND( 


OR( 
BillingCountry = "Argentina" , 
BillingCountry = "Portugal" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{8} ")) 
),AND( 

OR( 
BillingCountry = "Brazil" ), 
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\\d{9} ")) 
),AND( 

))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got one big `OR` join and that means any single criterion being fulfilled meets the entire validation criteria (hence the error). All your inner `OR` calls are redundant.

What you would really want for a particular subgrouping is:

```
AND(
    NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "<expression>")),
    OR(
        BillingCountry = "A",
        BillingCountry = "B",
        BillingCountry = "C"
    )
)
```

You can actually make this more efficient as well by using a `CASE` function:

```
AND(
    NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "<expression>")),
    1 = CASE(
        BillingCountry,
        "A", 1,
        "B", 1,
        "C", 1,
        0
    )
)
```

So in the broader context, your formula should look like:

```
OR(
    AND(
        NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, '<expression1>')),
        1 = CASE(BillingCountry, 'countrygroup1', 1, 0)
    ),
    AND(
        NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, '<expression2>')),
        1 = CASE(BillingCountry, 'countrygroup2', 1, 0)
    ), etc.
)
```

Comment: How would you put those countries in the "countrygroup1" I've tried "("Austria:Germany:Liechtenstein:Switzerland", Country), " but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: See the example above it. The syntax doesn't change.